# How to inherit type info for overriden methods using jsdoc in vscode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm using javascript with jsdoc type hints and vscode typescript type checking.

When adding jsdoc type info for a parent method, I'd like the overrides in child classes to inherit the parameter/return types.

E.g. I've got classes like these:

```js
class Parent {
  /**
   * @param {string} a ...
   * @param {number} b ...
   */
  method(a, b) {
    // ...
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  /** @inheritdocs */
  method(a, b) {
    super(a, b);
    // ... do extra stuff ...
  }
}
```

I'd like `Child#method` to automatically pick up the types from `Parent#method`. I tried `@inheritdocs`, but it doesn't seem to do this. Is that any way to mark this up?

Comment: Looking at the [jsdoc tags that typescript supports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#supported-jsdoc), it doesn't look possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
class Parent {
  /**
   * @param {string} a ...
   * @param {number} b ...
   */
  method(a, b) {
    // ...
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  /** @type {Parent['method']} */
  method(a, b) {
    super.method(a, b);
    // ... do extra stuff ...
  }
}
```

Which will help VScode infer the types:

[image: vs-code recognizes type]

Note that it will only work with typescript js-docs.

By the way, webstorm managed to identify the type on his own, without any help from me...

Although I really like VScode, I'd say that in this case -

Webstorm : 1
VScode : 0

[image: webstorm]